# python kinterbasdb - different encoding for varchar and blob

Tags: python, kinterbasdb

I have table with 
  USER VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET WIN1250,
  NOTE BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 CHARACTER SET WIN1250,

But when I pick up data from this table with kinterbasdb in python 2.7 (# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-) VARCHAR field is ok but BLOB field seems to be "corrupted" and I must decode it with decode('cp1250'). Why this happens? Why it is necessary to decode BLOB field only and not VARCHAR?

Thanks for help

Comment: As you have declared the BLOB as sub-type 1 i.e. text, i guess it is a bug in the db interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to call `KInterbasDB.init(type_conv=300)`:
http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/python/3.3.0/beyond-python-db-api.html#parameter-conversion